# How to get parseFloat() of currency?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table element :

```
<td class="commision_value">&pound; 40.89</td>
```

Now i want to get the float value of this td using jquery 
So i do

```
alert(parseFloat($(".commision_value").text()));
```

but it returns NaN instead of 40.89.

can some one tell me the problem ?

Comment: There are many possible tricks but depending on the context, especially if the formatting can change (some units are placed after the value), it would be cleaner to add the value in a data attribute.

Comment: Another option is using `class` (so `class="gpb"` for example) and then using the CSS3 `.gpb:before` pseudo-element to insert the currency symbol. Then your element value/text is just the pure number.

Answer (score 1):

A almost reliable solution would be to use a regex to get the number part :

```
var value = parseFloat($(".commision_value").text().match(/[\d\.]+/)[0]);
```

But depending on the context, especially if the formatting can change (some units are placed after the value, some number formattings involve spaces, etc.), it would be cleaner to add the value in a data attribute :

```
<td class="commision_value" data-value="40.89">&pound; 40.89</td>

var value = $(".commision_value").data('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

The *better* solution here is to store the raw number in an attribute when you build the element in the first place:

```
<td class="commision_value" data-value="40.89">&pound; 40.89</td>
```

Then, when you want to read it there's no need to parse out the pound sign, or anything else

```
alert($(".commision_value").data('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pound and anything else that is not a number or `.` or `,`

```
alert(parseFloat($("#test").text().replace(/[^\d.,]/g,'')));
```

Comment: parseFloat("3,400") will get you 3.